# Error inflating class <unknown> [Android]

Tags: java, android, xml, preferences

I'm trying to implement a preferences fragment in my app but I get a weird error when I open the fragment in the app.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.stairsapps.elohel, PID: 9611
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:164)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:148)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:510)
        at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:487)
        at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:246)
        ...
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {


public SettingsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Layout"
    android:summary="Display the jokes in a list"
    android:key="layout_mode"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    ></CheckBoxPreference></PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: A quick look around Google suggests that there are several questions that ask the same thing; did you explore any of those solutions?

Comment: I haven't found anything useful. I don't even have 20 lines on my xml

Comment: Change `<CheckBoxPreference android:title="Layout" android:summary="Display the jokes in a list" android:key="layout_mode" android:defaultValue="true" ></CheckBoxPreference>` with `<CheckBoxPreference android:title="Layout" android:summary="Display the jokes in a list" android:key="layout_mode" android:defaultValue="true" />` and try again.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski still no luck :(

Comment: In which folder located that xml file? Drawable, layout or smth else ?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski in the xml folder in res

Comment: I have faced the problem with the folder under `res` . That's why can you try it again with moving the file to another **existing** folder? Please, try it and tell me what happens.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I can't add it in another folder, i get mismatch error when i addPreferencesFromResource

Comment: I am getting the same error in one of my testing device..But it works fine on another device